# React TypeScript 16.8 Passing Props with BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is the component that gets loaded as one of the routes. I have declared the type of companyName as a string within the type names AppProps and then told the component the type with `<AppProps>` and then later used `{companyName}` in the html. This feels right but I cant understand how to pass the property from the BrowserRouter. Is this where hooks come in or am i just missing something?

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../images/logo.svg';


type AppProps = {
  companyName: string
}

const Home: React.FC<AppProps> = ({companyName}) => {
  return (

    <div className="home-grid">
      <div className="logo">
        <h1><a href="/"><img src={logo} alt="My Logo" /></a></h1>
        <h2 className="strapline">{companyName}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default Home;
```

and this is the router

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './home';
import NotFound from './error';

const Router: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path = '/' component = {Home} />
        <Route component = {NotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `render` or `children` instead of `component`.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/children-func

```
<Route exact path="/"
  render={routeProps => (
    <Home
      {...routeProps}
      companyName="Company Name"
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Because its TypeScript do we need to somehow say that companyName is a string here too?